# Loading .gif in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, gif, animated-gif

I have an app with 3 views, 2 of them are tableViews (**lists**) and on the third view Im trying load gifs through passing data (text and gifs), different for each item in the list.

[image]

I have found an extension to play gifs called **SwiftGif**, which works great when using in ordinary *viewControllers*, but the gif is not moving when passing data between *tableViews*.

**SwiftGif** contains function:

```
extension UIImageView {

public func loadGif(name: String) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let image = UIImage.gif(name: name)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

And my **ThirdView.swift** file contains:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import ImageIO

let name = String()
var gifs =  UIImage.gif(name: name)


struct IngredientsAndDirections {
  var ThirdViewArray = [String]()
  var Pic = [gifs]
}
```

But I can't figure out how to call the loadGif function on the array of gifs to make my gifs moving.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is looking for a solution (Swift 4).

1. I implemented library https://github.com/swiftgif/SwiftGif
2. Created arrays with Name and Images (var name: NSArray = [], var images: NSArray = []
3. In viewDidLoad inserted all of the arrays (name = ["", "", ""] and images = ["", "", ""] -> the count must be the same)
4. Created TableViewCell.swift file, inserted all of the data
5. Through passing data everything works as a charm, the gifs even move in tableViews

Answer (score 1):

There is one library called [FLAnimatedImage](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage). You can use this library in your code.

> After this you just need to import the class and put your gif image inside your resource folder in your Xcode.

```
import FLAnimatedImage
```

> Then you need to use the following code to see your gif
>   animation.

```
guard let gifImageUrl = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "gifImage", ofType: "gif") else { return }
let gifData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: gifImageUrl))
let animGIFImage = FLAnimatedImage(animatedGIFData: gifData)
yourImageView.animatedImage = animGIFImage
```

Note:-

> Define your imageView class name as FLAnimatedImageView in your
>   storyboard file and your outlet should be like this @IBOutlet weak var
>   imageView: FLAnimatedImageView!

Comment: Thank you for reply, now the only problem seems to be the last part of your code ImageView.animatedImage = animGIFImage, which gives me an error: Expressions are not allowed at the top level and Use of unresolved identifier ImageView, the outlet is in other file.

Comment: So you need to define your imageView class name as FLAnimatedImageView in your storyboard file and your outlet should be like this @IBOutlet weak var imageView: FLAnimatedImageView!

Answer (score 0):

use this repo
[kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)
Here is the sample code for support any image type.

```
self.imageView.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: UIImage(named: "ic_DefaultImage"),options: [.cacheSerializer(FormatIndicatedCacheSerializer.gif),.cacheSerializer(FormatIndicatedCacheSerializer.png),.cacheSerializer(FormatIndicatedCacheSerializer.jpeg)])
```